# How to return a field with text?

Tags: razor

Hi there I am building a web page that shows data from database. Like this:

[image]

Why the result does not shown? Best,

```
@model Orchard.Staff.Models.StaffPart
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Map Fields</legend>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffID)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StaffID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffID)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CName)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EName)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EName)
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EName)
```

instead of,

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EName)
```

if that doesn't work, make sure you model is being populated correctly before it's sent to the view